# Help with notation in second order tensor.

Tags: notation, tensor-products, tensors

I have seen recently this notation:
$$F=F_{ij}\,e_i\otimes e_j $$

Where $F_{ij}=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_j}$ is the tensor matrix:

$$      F=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial X_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial X_2} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial X_3} \\
 \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial X_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial X_2} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial X_3} \\
 \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial X_1} & \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial X_3} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial X_3} \\
                \end{array} } \right]
$$

I don't understand the intuition behind that notation neither what is useful for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you write refers, in general, to an element in the tensor product of modules over a ring, or vector spaces over a field.

Let us try to write an example involving the explicit definition of $F_{ij}$.

Let $x_i:=f_i$, with $f_i=f_i(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ denote the components of a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. The matrix $F$ with entries $F_{ij}$ is just the Jacobian of $f$ at $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ w.r.t. the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$ (usually one uses the canonical basis). With some abuse of notation we write $F\in\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^3)$.
Let us denote by $\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3\}$ the dual basis on ${(\mathbb R^3)}^{*}$. Using the chain of isomorphisms of vector spaces over $\mathbb R$

$$\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^3)\stackrel{I}{\leftarrow} \mathbb R^3\otimes {(\mathbb R^3)}^{*}\leftarrow \mathbb R^3\otimes\mathbb R^3,$$

where the leftmost isomorphism is given by

$$I(e_i\otimes \epsilon_j)(e_k):=e_i\epsilon_j(e_k)= e_i\delta_{jk},$$

one can identify $F\in\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^3)$ with the element in $\mathbb R^3\otimes\mathbb R^3$ given by $F_{ij}~e_i\otimes e_j$ (using Einstein notation).

Comment: Is it possible to explain this with a geometrical interpretation?

Comment: Hello @Janus Gowda. A question: what do you mean with geometrical? Are you thinking about curvature and similar concepts? If yes, then the first step would probably be to define the vector space $V$ lying in the background: in my interpretation $V=\mathbb R^3$. In differential geometry one could consider, for example, $V=T_xM$, with $M$ real manifold.

Comment: Well actually I have seen this a a class on computational mechanics. So I don't know even if I'm asking the right questions. I'm a little lost here but it is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Basically you have the Jacobian matrix of a vector valued function whose components are $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and which depend on the "coordinates" $X_1, X_2, X_3$. In the OP one wants to describe the jacobian matrix (at a fixed point) as coefficients of an element of a suitable tensor product space. Please, feel free to add some background in the OP: I will try to adapt my answer to the updated setting.